# How do I replace a string value with a NULL in PySpark for all my columns in the dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

As an example say I have a df

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("v", "x", "y", "z")
df = sc.parallelize([
    row("p", 1, 2, 3.0), row("NULL", 3, "NULL", 5.0),
    row("NA", None, 6, 7.0), row(float("Nan"), 8, "NULL", float("NaN"))
]).toDF()
```

Now I want to replace NULL, NA and NaN by pyspark null (None) value. How do I achieve it for multiple columns together.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col
def replace(column, value):
    return when(column != value, column).otherwise(lit(None))

df = df.withColumn("v", replace(col("v"), "NULL"))
df = df.withColumn("v", replace(col("v"), "NaN"))
df = df.withColumn("v", replace(col("v"), "NaN"))
```

Writing this for all columns is something I am trying to avoid as I can have any number of columns in my dataframe.

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the columns, construct the column expressions that replace specific strings with `null`, then `select` the *columns*:

```py
df.show()
+----+----+----+---+
|   v|   x|   y|  z|
+----+----+----+---+
|   p|   1|   2|3.0|
|NULL|   3|null|5.0|
|  NA|null|   6|7.0|
| NaN|   8|null|NaN|
+----+----+----+---+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
cols = [F.when(~F.col(x).isin("NULL", "NA", "NaN"), F.col(x)).alias(x)  for x in df.columns]
df.select(*cols).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|   v|   x|   y|   z|
+----+----+----+----+
|   p|   1|   2| 3.0|
|null|   3|null| 5.0|
|null|null|   6| 7.0|
|null|   8|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: could there be an explanation of  how "
cols = [F.when(~F.col(x).isin("NULL", "NA", "NaN"), F.col(x)).alias(x)  for x in df.columns]
"
works?